# determine whether graph is planar

Tags: graph-theory

This is not a HW question just a practice exercise in the text.

[image]
The question is to determine whether its planar or not. I dont think its Planar and I cant find a subgraph that is homeomorphic to $k_{3,3}$ or $K_5$.  I have a feeling I might be wrong and if I am right i.e the graph is not planar then how do I Show its not Planar.

I would appreciate a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you collapse h,i,j and also c,e then I think a,b,{c,e},d,{h,i,j} is a $K_5$

Edit: And so it isn't planar as it contains $K_5$ as a minor.

Comment: hmm, so when we collapse ${h,i,j}$ does the edge $aj$ disappear or can it be used to get back to $a$ and make &K_5$

Comment: No all the edges stay, a graph minor is obtained from a graph by deleting edges, vertices and contracting edges. So when I say collapse $h,i,j$, I really mean contract the edges $hi$, $ij$. Then  we get a new vertex ${h,i,j}$ and any distinct vertex $x$ is adjacent to ${h,i,j}$ iff it was adjacent to $h$ or $i$ or $j$ previously. The wikipedia article is pretty good. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(graph_theory)

Comment: +1 Maybe just reference Kuratowski's theorem for completeness.

Comment: thank you very much James and Andrew